# How to Search for a pattern at all columns in pandas dataframe and when find it copy it to another column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am having a problem with my Dataframe.
I imported it from pdf file using tabula , and after many modification I reached the cleaning level of that

[image]

the problem is that some data got shifted to the right with different columns 
i want to bring the data from the red area to the green area

i guess that the solution is to search with account code pattern (red color) using regex (\d{6}-\d{4}) in all of columns of df and when find it matched , copy it to the green cells

note 1 : I can't search with column names since it changes from file to file
note 2 : there isn't a specific wrong columns that the account code appears in , but rather we have to search in all columns

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the note at the end of the question. But as it is a dataframe, there's surely the header. Let's say that the header of the column with green area is named "Green" and the header of the column with red area is "Red"

```
# df is the dataframe
df["Green"] = df.apply(lambda row : row["Red"] if re.search("\d{6}-\d{4}", row["Red"]) and pd.isnull(row["Green"]) else row["Green"], axis=1)

# if the columns have the same order
col_for_green = df.columns[1]
for col in [c for c in list(df) if c != col_for_green]:
     df[col_for_green] = df.apply(lambda row : row[x] if re.search("\d{6}-\d{4}", row[x]) and pd.isnull(row[col_for_green]) else row[col_for_green], axis=1)
```

Comment: The problem is column names ( green and red ) are different from dataframe to another , and i want a generic solution for each dataframe ,, so is there any way to search the whole dataframe without specifying the column name ?

Comment: In this case, if the columns have the same order. You can replace "Green" by df.columns[1]. The number 1 relates to the column's postion.

Comment: We can say Green column is fixed among all files , but Unfortunately Red column can be anywhere

Comment: That's the reason way there's a loop for all columns : `for col in [c for c in list(df) if c != col_for_green]:`

Answer (score 0):

As you presented your Excel file without the top row, I assumed that it contains
only data rows, without any column names.

So I created an Excel file containing a part of your source data, read it calling:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Input.xlsx', header=None)
```

and got:

```
             0   1   2                    3          4          5            6              7        8        9
0  401042-0000 NaN NaN  Masonry Accessories   30105.05    57928.1          NaN            NaN      NaN      NaN 
1  401043-0100 NaN NaN   Brick Masonry unit  763897.00  1237457.0          NaN            NaN      NaN      NaN 
2          NaN NaN NaN                  NaN        NaN        NaN  401079-0000  Joint sealers  18514.6  53145.0 
3          NaN NaN NaN                  NaN        NaN        NaN  401088-0000        Glazing      0.0      0.0 
4  401160-0200 NaN NaN             Conducts  198961.00   198961.0          NaN            NaN      NaN      NaN 
5  401160-0400 NaN NaN   Low Voltage Cables   36403.00    36403.0          NaN            NaN      NaN      NaN
```

The task to perform can be expressed as:

- in each row,
- fill column **0** (updateit) with a value from first subsequent column
  matching `\d{6}-\d{4}` pattern,
- if any.

To do it I defined the following function to be applied to each row:

```
def mtch(row):
    s = row.iloc[1:].str.match(r'\d{6}-\d{4}').fillna(False)
    indLst = s[s].index.tolist()
    return row.loc[indLst[0]] if len(indLst) > 0 else np.nan
```

When you apply it calling: `df.apply(mtch, axis=1)`, the result is:

```
0            NaN
1            NaN
2    401079-0000
3    401088-0000
4            NaN
5            NaN
dtype: object
```

So to update column **0** in *df*, run:

```
df[0].update(df.apply(mtch, axis=1))
```

Now when you `print(df)` the result:

```
             0   1   2                    3          4          5            6              7        8        9
0  401042-0000 NaN NaN  Masonry Accessories   30105.05    57928.1          NaN            NaN      NaN      NaN 
1  401043-0100 NaN NaN   Brick Masonry unit  763897.00  1237457.0          NaN            NaN      NaN      NaN 
2  401079-0000 NaN NaN                  NaN        NaN        NaN  401079-0000  Joint sealers  18514.6  53145.0 
3  401088-0000 NaN NaN                  NaN        NaN        NaN  401088-0000        Glazing      0.0      0.0 
4  401160-0200 NaN NaN             Conducts  198961.00   198961.0          NaN            NaN      NaN      NaN 
5  401160-0400 NaN NaN   Low Voltage Cables   36403.00    36403.0          NaN            NaN      NaN      NaN
```

So now column **0** has 2 missing fields filled.

## Edit

From your second picture (mentioned in the comment) I see that you must have
made some operations leading to a very weird result.

Note that:

- the left part contains data preceded with column names (*Unnamed: 0*
  thru *Unnamed: 7* and *COMMENT* (so far OK),
- but the right part contains data rows **without** column names,
- and the effect it that the first row in your file is a mixture of
  column names and data.

I think that this issue is a good material for **another** question.
It is a bad habit to put one question and then gradually "expand" it
with another issues, not mentioned before.

Comment: A very good job man but now i want to delete the original account code from the red area ( Cut instead of copy ) ,, plus there is another problem , i found an account code that was scraped wrong next to the headers in the first row , so i want to search that pattern in the first row as well and if i found it i cut it in the last cell column of the dataframe

Comment: As I understood, what is marked as the "red area" in your source data sample
is in the *df* in column titled **6**.
To drop this column, run *df.drop(columns=[6], inplace=True)*.
Now there is a "gap" in column numeration (columns 0-5 and then 7-9), but I think it is not important.
The final goal (as I assume) is to save this DataFrame is some file,
without column names and probably also without the index. Or now you can set any meaningful column names.

Comment: check this picture https://ibb.co/6gmXMCg,,, now i want to cut the red cells and put it in the end of the dataframe just as the other items ( account code in the first column , then description , etc )  ,,